# Dynamic Index Pattern @ Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to create an index pattern on Kibana dynamically based on index name created by logstash.

How can I achive it ?

Comment: check this tutorial https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html

Comment: I need create index patten in code, not like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create index pattern either through front end or console with below query

```
POST .kibana/_doc/index-pattern:<index-name>
{
  "type" : "index-pattern",
  "index-pattern" : {
    "title": "index-*",  ---> pattern to match index
    "timeFieldName": "execution_time"
  }
}
```

Query to see index patterns

```
GET .kibana/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "type": "index-pattern"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```